# Can you create fungible tokens out of a single non-fungible token?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, dapps, erc-721, crowdsale

As you are aware, ERC20 tokens are fungible tokens and ERC721 are non-fungible tokens. Click [here](https://101blockchains.com/fungible-vs-non-fungible-tokens/#:%7E:text=Fungible%20tokens%20are%20easily%20interchangeable,of%20them%20represents%20unique%20assets.&text=Fungible%20tokens%20depend%20on%20the,leverage%20the%20ERC%2D721%20standard.) for details if you want to read about them.

Assuming you have a non-fungible digital asset such as art tokenized as 1 token. Can I further tokenize that art to many fungible tokens so I can start selling it fractionally to many users? Something like the concept of crowdfunding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Nothing stops you from creating a contract which owns the NFT. The contract may have whatever logic to manage the NFT and it may even itself be an ERC20.

There are probably also EIP standards for such, but no idea which. Or you could directly consider using a multi-type standard: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155

Comment: You should make sure, that you have a mechanic to get the NFT out of the contract again somehow. If it is locked away forever, it's basically worthless.